# How do I set up a 3rd person character with multiple animations in the Game Engine?

Tags: game-engine

I am using the Blender Game Engine to make a 3rd person game. I want the main character to have separate armatures/animations for the upper body and the lower body. For example I'd want my character to be able to jump, crouch, and run while shooting and aiming a gun. I have tried to make two armature modifiers but only my leg armature deforms my mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use only one armature for your character.

Create your two different actions on the same armature. Make sure that **no bone is used in different actions at the same time**. (In your case: action one -> exclusively the upper body part, action two -> only bones of the lower half)

Last thing you have to do, is to select **different Action-Layers** for your actions in each action-actuator.

[image]